# Analyze identification number with 12 digits

Tags: c#

i have to analyse 12 digit number. So i got stuck on between 7th and 8th number. I want if the number is 40(digit 7th is 4, digit 8 is 0) to give me "ex.London", if it is 45 to give me "ex.NY" ...

code :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string ID(string number)
    {
        int fullInt = Int32.Parse(number);
        string City1= number.Substring(0, 2);
        string City1_S = "Date of birth: " + City1;

        string City2 = number.Substring(2,2);
        string City2_S = "Month: " + City2;

        string City3 = number.Substring(4, 3);
        string City3_S = "Year: 1" + City3;

        string City4 = number.Substring(7, 2).Contains("40").ToString();
        string City4_S = "City: London";

        string[] Array= new string[3];
        Array[0] = City1_S.ToString();
        Array[1] = City2_S.ToString();
        Array[2] = City3_S.ToString();
        Array[3] = City4_S.ToString();

        return Array.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: How does the mapping from a number to `ex.*` work?

Comment: Please add more detail before we are able to help you.

Comment: Since City4_S is a string, there is no need to call ToString() on it again.

Comment: You'll need to declare your array as string[4] also.  Currently you only have allocated enough for 3 elements.

Comment: `string City4 = number.Substring(7,2).Contains("40").ToString()` is going to turn your Boolean result into a string ("true" or "false"). Intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[WebMethod]
public string ID(string number)
{
    int fullInt = Int32.Parse(number);// if (Regex.IsMatch(number, @"\D")) throw new ArgumentException();
    string City1_S = "Date of birth: " + number.Substring(0, 2);
    string City2_S = "Month: " + number.Substring(2,2);
    string City3_S = "Year: 1" + number.Substring(4, 3);

    string City4_S = "";
    var digitStr = number.Substring(7, 2);
    switch (digitStr)
    {
        case "40":
             City4_S = "City: London";
             break;
        case "45":
             City4_S = "City: NY";
             break;
    }

    string[] Array = new [] { City1_S,  City2_S, City3_S, City4_S };

    return Array.ToString();//something wrong =)
    //return string.Join(" ", Array);
    //return Array[0] + " " + Array[1] + " " + Array[2] + " " + Array[3];
}
```

Comment: @PetarStojkovski Is the first line, `int fullInt = Int32.Parse(number);`, needed? `Int32.Parse` will throw an exception on a 12-digit number (unless leading digits are `0`). If you need a 12-digit integer, you can use `long` (`Int64`).

Comment: Yes you're right @JeppeStigNielsen, that was thee issue in continuing my code, in if-else statement i had a problem, now that works too, thanks.